# creating a stack using two queues in c, dequeue is not working

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, queue, stack

So I am creating a stack using two queues in C.
And I am given `enqueue`, `dequeue` and `printQueue`.
Unfortunately my `dequeue` for one of my queues is not working properly, below is what I have written thus far:

```
int isQueueEmpty(Queue *queue)
{
    if (queue == NULL) return 1;
    else if (queue->head == NULL) return 1;
    else return 0;
}

//// Do not modify this ////
void enqueue(Queue **queue, void *item)
{
    if (*queue == NULL)
        *queue = malloc(sizeof(Queue));
    if ((*queue)->head == NULL)
    {
        (*queue)->head = malloc(sizeof(Node));
        (*queue)->head->data = item;
        (*queue)->head->next = NULL;
        (*queue)->tail = (*queue)->head;
    }
    else
    {
        Node *temp = malloc(sizeof(Node));
        (*queue)->tail->next = temp;
        temp->data = item;
        temp->next = NULL;
        (*queue)->tail = temp;
    }
}

//// Do not modify this ////
void *dequeue(Queue *queue)
{
    if (queue == NULL || queue->head == NULL)
        return NULL;
    else
    {
        void *temp = queue->head->data;
        Node *tempNode = queue->head;
        queue->head = queue->head->next;
        free(tempNode);
        return temp;
    }
}

void printQueue(Queue *queue)
{
    if (queue != NULL)
    {
        printf("Queue content: {");
        Node *temp = queue->head;
        for (; temp != NULL; temp = temp->next)
        {
            printf("%d ", *(int* )(temp->data));
        }
        printf("}\n");
    }
    else
        printf("Uninitailized Queue\n");
}

Queue *q = NULL;
Queue *qu = NULL;

void push(void *item) {
    printf("reeter here\n");
    while (!isQueueEmpty(q)) {
        enqueue(&qu, q->head);
        printf("eleq: %d\n", *((int *)dequeue(q)));
    }
    enqueue(&q, item);
    while (!isQueueEmpty(qu)) {
        enqueue(&q, qu->head);
        dequeue(qu);
        //printf("elequ: %d\n", *((int *)dequeue(qu)));
    }
    printf("q:\n");
    printQueue(q);
    printf("qu:\n");
    printf("reached end\n");
    printQueue(qu);
}
```

Unfortunately my dequeue for my second queue is not removing the element properly cause the second loop in `pop()` to perform and infinite loop.
Secondly the data stored in the queue after queuing it an dereferencing it came back as an address rather than what I input in:

```
reeter here
q:
Queue content: {1}
qu:
reached end
Uninitailized Queue
reeter here
eleq: 1
q:
Queue content: {21519347601}
qu:
reached end
Queue content: {}
reeter here
eleq: 2
eleq: -159836464
q:
Queue content: {3-1598364641519347601}
qu:
reached end
Queue content: {}
Queue content: {3-1598364641519347601}
3
-159836464
1519347601
reeter here
```

this is the result I have received from my shell. Hence how do I firstly fix the `push()` function so it actually pushes and stores the desired data and how do I dequeue the second queue properly without using modifying `dequeue`.
Thank you

Comment: When you've done `*queue = malloc(sizeof(Queue);` you seem to expect `if ((*queue)->head == NULL)` to make sense. It doesn't. The memory you `malloc`ed is uninitialized so `head` could point anywhere.

Comment: Running a build compiled with `-fsanitize=address` is great at finding and debugging these problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a problem in the `dequeue` function: it does not update the `tail` pointer when the last element is popped from the queue.  This does not cause a problem because of the implementation of `enqueue` tests `head` first, but it is nevertheless risky to make `tail` a dangling pointer in this case.

I understand you ar not supposed to modify these functions, but here is a modified version for educational purposes:

```
void *dequeue(Queue *queue)
{
    if (queue == NULL || queue->head == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    } else {
        Node *tempNode = queue->head;
        queue->head = queue->head->next;
        if (!queue->head)
            queue->tail = NULL;
        void *temp = tempNode->data;
        free(tempNode);
        return temp;
    }
}
```

Note also these problems in `enqueue`:

- it is cumbersome and error prone to dereference the function argument multiple times.
- initialization code should be factorized
- allocation error should be tested and reported:

Here is a modified version for you to study:

```
int enqueue(Queue **queue_p, void *item)
{
    Queue *queue = *queue_p;

    if (*queue == NULL) {
        *queue_p = queue = malloc(sizeof(*queue));
        if (queue == NULL) {
            // allocation error, report failure
            return -1;
        }
    }
    Node *node = malloc(sizeof(*node));
    if (node == NULL) {
        // allocation error, report failure
        return -1;
    }
    node->data = item;
    node->next = NULL;
    if (queue->head == NULL) {
        queue->tail = queue->head = node;
    } else {
        queue->tail = queue->tail->next = node;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Regarding your code, the function `push()` has several problems:

- you enqueue `q->head` instead of `q->head->data`. You should actually use the return value of `dequeue()` instead of breaking the encapsulation. The current code enqueues a pointer that will be freed by `dequeue`, causing undefined behavior.

Here is a modified version of `push()`:

```
void push(void *item)
{
    printf("reenter here\n");
    while (!isQueueEmpty(q)) {
        int *data = dequeue(q);
        enqueue(&qu, data);
        //printf("eleq: %d\n", *data);
    }
    enqueue(&q, item);
    while (!isQueueEmpty(qu)) {
        int *data = dequeue(qu);
        enqueue(&q, data);
        //printf("elequ: %d\n", *data);
    }
    printf("q:\n");
    printQueue(q);
    printf("qu:\n");
    printQueue(qu);
    printf("reached end\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code isn't enqueuing the items properly in the first place. In two of the `enqueue()` calls in the `push()` function, you are passing a `Node *` parameter , whereas it should be rightly passed as a `void *` parameter to the item you are actually enqueueing.

The following code change should work:

```
   void push(void * item) {
    while(!isQueueEmpty(q)){
        enqueue(&qu, q->head->data);
        printf("eleq: %d\n", *((int*)dequeue(q)));
    }
    enqueue(&q, item);
    while(!isQueueEmpty(qu)){
        enqueue(&q, qu->head->data);
        printf("elequ: %d\n", *((int*)dequeue(qu)));
    }
    printf("q:\n");
    printQueue(q);
    printf("qu:\n");
    printf("reached end\n");
    printQueue(qu);
}
```

As you have not shared what the declaration of `item` looks like, I tested with an `item` declared as a `int *` from `main()`, now the calls to `push()` work correctly. For a test pushing items 1 through 4 from `main()`, removing items from the front of the queue `q` at the end of the program will simulate a stack ordering now:

```
$./stackqtest.exe
q:
Queue content: {1 }
qu:
reached end
Uninitailized Queue
eleq: 1
elequ: 1
q:
Queue content: {2 1 }
qu:
reached end
Queue content: {}
eleq: 2
eleq: 1
elequ: 2
elequ: 1
q:
Queue content: {3 2 1 }
qu:
reached end
Queue content: {}
eleq: 3
eleq: 2
eleq: 1
elequ: 3
elequ: 2
elequ: 1
q:
Queue content: {4 3 2 1 }
qu:
reached end
Queue content: {}
```